# Inequalities between sums of products of certain binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am a PhD student. During my researches, I often have to deal with inequalities involving sums of binomial coefficients, where the sums are indexed by some set of integer compositions. For example, let $l,k$ be positive integers such that $l \leq k$ and either $l$ is odd or both $l$ and $k$ are even. One of my results can be proven if I show that for any $i \leq k \lfloor \frac{l}{2}\rfloor - 1$:

$$
\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{\alpha \models i+k} \\ \ell(\alpha) = k \\ \alpha_a \leq \lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor + 1} \prod_{a=1}^k \binom{l}{2(\alpha_a - 1)}
\leq 
\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{\alpha \models i+l} \\ \ell(\alpha) = l \\ \alpha_a \leq \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor + 1} \prod_{a=1}^l \binom{k}{2(\alpha_a - 1)},
$$

where the notations under the left sum means that we take the sum over all $\alpha = (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k) \subseteq \{1,...,\lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor + 1\}^k$ such that $\alpha_1 + ... + \alpha_k = k+i$, and analogously for the other.

My question here is not about solving this problem in particular (although if the solution is easy feel free to give it).

My question is rather: how do you work with such sums? I am not used to these kinds of formulas, and while it is manageable when $l$ and $k$ are small, they become hard very rapidly. So, is there a trick to understand these kind of sums? Is there some already known results? Is there formulas? Combinatorial arguments?

Comment: You are right, as I add +1 to obtain composition without zeroes. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Currently the inequality seems to hold only if $l$ and $k$ have the same parity.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten a restriction on i. It's add now.

Comment: Hi @eti902 , did you find out the tricks to analyze these sum over compositions/partitions? I recently involve this type of sum in my research as well, and didn't gain much about how to deal with them in a general way. Though I found some examples in Richard Stanley's book of enumerative combinatorics. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the LHS:
$$\sum_{\substack{\alpha \models i+k} \\ \ell(\alpha) = k \\ \alpha_a \leq \lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor} \prod_{a=1}^k \binom{l}{2(\alpha_a - 1)}$$
Firstly, we can simplifying by rolling the subtraction of one into the definition of $\alpha$:
$$\sum_{\substack{\sum \alpha_a = i \\ \ell(\alpha) = k \\ 0 \leq \alpha_a < \lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor}} \prod_{a=1}^k \binom{l}{2\alpha_a}$$
The constraint on the sum of the $\alpha_a$ can be done with coefficient extraction:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
& [x^{2i}] \sum_{\substack{\ell(\alpha) = k \\ 0 \leq \alpha_a < \lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor}} \prod_{a=1}^k \binom{l}{2\alpha_a} x^{2\alpha_a} \\
=& [x^{2i}] \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor - 1} \binom{l}{2\alpha_a} x^{2\alpha_a} \right)^k \\
=& [x^{2i}] \left( \frac{ (1+x)^l + (1-x)^l }2 - \binom{l}{l - l \bmod 2}x^{l - l \bmod 2}  \right)^k
\end{eqnarray*}$$

One (untested) idea to show that the coefficients of the polynomial corresponding to the LHS don't exceed those of the RHS would be to take the $2i^{\textrm{th}}$ derivative and evaluate it at zero.

Comment: It is easy to come up with the case when the degree of polynomial in the lhs is larger than that in the rhs, leading to a counterexample.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of tricks I was looking for, thanks!